# can't login to phpmyadmin on centos7

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, centos, centos7

i installed apache and phpmyadmin on centos7 and apache and phpmyadmin are

running correctly , but when i want to login to phpmyadmin its say's:
 `Cannot log in to the MySQL server`  the confirugation i have done in the `etc\phpmyadmin\config.inc.php` is :

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user']          = 'unlocker';          // MySQL user
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password']      = '123456789';          // MySQL password (only needed
```

but its not loging in whit this username and password.

thanks.

Comment: what auth type are you using? `$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'cookie';`

Comment: @ßiansor Å. Ålmerol i'm using cookie too.